# Tricky RxJS Problem: Debouncing a stream while implementing Mutual Exclusion on an async function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

We have an RxJS stream of (form) values in our frontend, let's call it `formValue$`. As values come in, they ought to get saved to the backend via an asynchronous function `save()`. `save()` computes the changes from the last saved value and triggers one or several HTTP calls if there are changes.

However, as each single key-press in the form triggers a new emission on `formValue$`, we don't want to trigger `save()` for *every* value from `formValue$` - not only would that trigger way too many HTTP calls, it also runs into a race condition problem with writing/reading the last saved value. Instead we want to take the first value, trigger `save()`, *wait for `save()` to complete* (and potentially wait for a few more seconds), then take the *latest* value from `formValue$` and trigger `save()` again.

We've read [this article](https://medium.com/@jan.benscheid/mutual-exclusion-using-rxjs-f5f3a11237b7) on using RxJS (and in particular concatMap) for MutEx, and came up with the following (using the [audit](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/audit) operator):

```
// formValue$ would be passed as stream$, the save function as handler
function getEventSkippingMutExQueue<Event, Result>(
  stream$: Observable<Event>,
  handler: (e: Event) => Promise<Result>
): Observable<Result> {
  let handlingFinished$ = new Subject<Result>() // could also be Subject<void>

  let eventSkippingStream = merge(
    stream$.pipe(take(1)), // make stream$'s first emission go through
    stream$.pipe(audit((_) => handlingFinished$))
  )
  // then only the latest one upon emission from handlingFinished$

  return eventSkippingStream.pipe(
    concatMap((input) => from(handler(input))),
    tap((value) => handlingFinished$.next(value))
  )
}
```

This works to wait for completion of the async handler function and to skip "bunched up" emissions in `formValue$` (only handling the latest upon `handlingFinished$` emissions).

Unfortunately, `audit` behaves in an inappropriate way: if there's nothing in `stream$` when `handlingFinished$` emits, the returned stream "stalls"/"dies off" - that is, new emissions from `stream$` don't trigger the `handler` anymore.

Here's a [stackblitz showing the behavior](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-cghrbd?file=index.ts). (I'm not sure how stackblitz works regarding editing, i.e. whether you could overwrite what we have there - so please fork if you want to play with the code).

Comment: Ref: *"not sure how stackblitz works regarding editing"* only you can modify your own stackblitz. When someone else tries to edit, a fork is automatically created. Nonetheless, having such concerns, why not create a fork yourself and share it, to completely eliminate the chance of someone messing up your *"original"*?

Comment: @tao thanks for the code beautification, and also thanks for the stackblitz clarification. Regarding "why not share a fork yourself": I wasn't concerned about losing the original code (I have it locally), but more with others seeing some person's "doodling" instead of my solution attempt.

Comment: Does [this recipe](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/recipes/save-indicator) help in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's (nearly) a built in operator for this: [exhaustMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/exhaustMap).

Here's the marble diagram for it:

[image]

In your case, because the HTTP request would return only 1 observable it'd rather look like this:

[image]

(note that on the inner stream, the value would be emitted exactly at the same position where the stream ends as it's just an HTTP request but it was too complicated to edit).

So we're nearly good here.

- The value 1 is being saved to our backend with no emissions meanwhile
- Then comes in value 3, saved to our backend except that it had an emission (5) meanwhile. Only value 3 was saved without interrupting the save in any way (or creating race condition). That said... Because 5 came in while 3 was being saved, there should be another save right after 3 has been saved from what I understood

While this isn't supported by the operator itself, someone created exactly the operator we need here: `exhaustmap-with-trailing`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-exhaustmap-with-trailing

Which is exactly an exhaustMap, except that if a value is being emitted while the exhaust was running, it'll emit the last one that was emitted in between at the end.

Comment: This does look exactly like what we need, and at first it seemed to work perfectly, [see this new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dpmrh3?file=index.ts). However, when I tweak the timeout numbers - specifically changing the timeout in the `handler` to 3000ms - it seems to consistently "miss" (i.e. not handle) the last emission (c8). Do you have any idea what's going on there?

Comment: I've tweaked the stackblitz to be clearer, the timeout in question is now in the `consoleLoggingHandler`

Comment: I've also opened [an issue](https://github.com/bjoerge/rxjs-exhaustmap-with-trailing/issues/7) on the exhaustmap-with-trailing's GitHub. Anxious to see if I'm missing something, or if there is indeed a bug in the operator.

Comment: Aha! I figured out what was going on: In the stackblitz linked above, I'm using version 1.x.y of exhaustmap-with-trailing (/rxjs v6). After updating to v2 (/rxjs v7), everything seems to behave exactly as desired!

Comment: Excellent! Glad you figured it out