# How to cancel all previous requests except the last one using NestJS and rxjs?

Tags: rxjs, nestjs

Imagine a situation where a complex request is being processed on the server. But the user can click on the button any number of times and send requests. I wanted to cancel all the old requests on server and work only with the current new one. What is the best way to do this?
My code is written below using NestJs and rxjs
Actually I dont know, is it good written because I am a beginner in rxjs. But I see the problem, if a user clicks button too much, server gives back a message about error with status 500. For me it is a problem, because all code gets in catch block.

```
@Controller('user')

export class UserController {

    constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}

    private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

    @Get()

    async findOne(@Query('email') email: string, @Query('username') username?: string) {
     
   this.destroy$.next(); //Sending a signal to cancel previous requests

        this.destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

        return of(true).pipe(

            delay(5000), // Simulation of a long response processing for 5 seconds

            switchMap(async () => {

                return this.userService.findOne(email, username);

            }),

            takeUntil(this.destroy$),

            catchError(() => {

                throw new HttpException('Request was canceled', HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);

            }),

        );

    }
}
```

Comment: I think what you're looking for is exhaustMap except that you'd need the last value. I've explained all this in details already there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77045060/2398593

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep only the most recently projected Observable, switchMap is the correct operator.

The problem is that all the api request are executed. You are just managing the results with switchMap.

What is needed here is the [debounce](https://angular.io/guide/http-optimize-server-interaction) operator